# Not show DIV when no input value for template-variable in MODx

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-evolution

My blog posts have either a VIDEO or an IMAGE, never both.
VIDEO and IMAGE are both template-variables in MODx Evolution CMS.
Now ALWAYS, a DIV section (be it blank space/area) for an image will show and below that a DIV for a video. I want only the image to show provided I input a template-variable for an image, and then no blank space for the video DIV. Similarly, when I input a template variable for a video, then I do not want a blank area/space for the DIV image space to show.

DIV for image:

```
<div class="image">
<img src="[*image*]">
</div>
```

DIV for video:

```
<div class="well">
<video width="400" controls>
 <source src="[*video*]" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="[*video*]" type="video/ogv">
</video>
   </div>
```

How to display the DIV when I input an IMAGE and thus not show any space for the VIDEO DIV? Or how to display the DIV when I input a VIDEO and thus not show any space for the IMAGE DIV? Some IF-THEN rule?

Comment: Don't put the tags in if you don't want them...leave the `<div>` tags out.

Comment: Doesn't your CMS have like an "if" feature? Also why are you specifying the same URL for both your media types?

Comment: I love that their documentation subdomain is `rtfm.modx.com`

Comment: @raulbaros: That doesn't show the state of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using the PHx extra and this code...

```
[+phx:if=`[*video*]`:ne=``:then=`<div class="well">
<video controls="" width="400">
 <source src="[*video*]" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="[*video*]" type="video/ogv">
</video></div>`+]
        </div>
```